# Custom database query doesn't work, what could be the problem?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I found out that this code doesn't injects the parameters to the SQL query.

> @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM schema.table WHERE schema.table.name = ':name'", nativeQuery = true)
> Optional findByName(@Param("name") String name);

In this case the database receives this:

> SELECT * FROM schema.table WHERE schema.table.name = ':name'

I tried with @Param too, then this is the case:

> @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM schema.table WHERE schema.table.name = '?1'", nativeQuery = true)
> Optional findByName(String name);

Then the database receives this:

> SELECT * FROM schema.table WHERE schema.table.name = '?1'

I tried without the single apostrophes (') as well.

Without @Query:

> Optional findByName(String name);

The DB receives this:

```
... WHERE myclass.name = $1
```

What could be the problem? I saw this solution many times and it worked for them. Basis queries are working, so that's not the problem I can't access the DB or something like that.

My application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa-hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring-jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgresPlusDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

And my pom.xml:

```
<properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring.version>2.6.6</spring.version>
        <tomcat7-maven-plugin.version>2.2</tomcat7-maven-plugin.version>
        <maven-war-plugin.version>3.3.2</maven-war-plugin.version>
        <javax.servlet-api.version>4.0.1</javax.servlet-api.version>
        <javax.persistence-api.version>2.2</javax.persistence-api.version>
        <spring-data-jpa.version>2.6.4</spring-data-jpa.version>
        <postgresql.version>42.3.4</postgresql.version>
        <commons-lang3.version>3.12.0</commons-lang3.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
                <version>${javax.persistence-api.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>${javax.servlet-api.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Renove the quotes. Also just ditch the `@Query` as Spring Data will generate that for you based on the `findByName` no need to write a query in the first place.

Comment: That is not solved the issue. :(

Comment: What is the issue? As that is not clear from your description? All queries you posted are wrong as they have queries, which will use the containing parameter as is (so no replacement). Without quotes it should work, but with Spring Data you don't even need the query. So now it is totally unclear what the issue is.

Comment: I said remove the `@Query`... It is still there.

Comment: I had remove it.

Comment: Please don't add additional code in comments as that is unreadable. Edit your question instead.

Comment: What the db recieves is fine, that is with parameters which are send also and the DB will interpret this. So there must be something else wrong andyou are looking at the wrong thing. So please describe what you expect and what you aren't getting..

Comment: Thanks for your help! The problem was in my controller, sadly.